# Protractor and ZAP proxy parameters

Tags: protractor, zap

Background: I am trying to intercept traffic using OWASP ZAP for an angularjs webpage. The documentation for protractor says I should be specifying proxy parameter as given below.

Problem: Starting ZAP version: 2.4.1, ZAP has introduced API authentication so I need to pass the authentication key in the proxy parameter to set the browser Desire capabilities.

Any idea how can I make ZAP intercept the traffic in this scenario??

'proxy': {
          'proxyType': 'manual',
          'httpsProxy': 'localhost:8090',   //ZAP configured at port 8090
          'sslProxy': 'localhost:8090'
         }

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the API key in order to proxy through ZAP. You only need the API key when accessing the ZAP API.

Comment: Thanks!! @Psiinon  that make sense.Any clue on why ZAP is not intercepting the traffic?

Comment: Check your browser's proxy settings and make sure that they are not excluding localhost and 127.0.0.1 - thats a common problem ;)